# QDir information changed

Tags: qt, qt4, qtreeview, qdir

I have a Qt application that creates a qtreeview based on the information of a QDir.
Is there a way that if the information on the directory changes (say i add a new file or remove an existing one), the qtreeview is updated?

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To monitor file system changes you can use [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfilesystemwatcher.html)

Comment: Thanks @savelkev I'm doing this `QFileSystemWatcher watcher; watcher.addPath("C:/QtTest"); connect(&watcher,  SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), mc, SLOT(showModified(QString)));` but nothing is happening, i'm not getting the signal. In the SlOT i have a cout << "hi" << endl, that is not being printed

Comment: @user1486311 Have you allocated `watcher` so that it lives long enough to actually emit a signal (so, not as a local variable in a function).

Comment: I used example code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044853/how-to-qfilesystemwatcher and it worked for me. I assume you try GUI application, which has nowhere to print STDOUT. Try that example yourself

Comment: I'm using that example, and is not working :S let me give it another try and i'll let you know in a few minutes! @saveljev

Comment: mm i think that might be an error i'm having @alexisdm, let me check it and i'll let you know