# Suppress warning "QApplication was not created in main() thread"

Tags: c++, qt, suppress-warnings, qcoreapplication

I've created a Qt-based network library for use with applications that are not running a Qt event loop, and which are not necessarily otherwise Qt applications. This was made possible by creating a `QCoreApplication` instance in a thread per the answer from [Is it possible to create local event loops without calling QApplication::exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801572/is-it-possible-to-create-local-event-loops-without-calling-qapplicationexec)

This works perfectly, but it makes Qt upset (I presume it's worried that I'll try to manipulate a GUI outside of the main thread which wouldn't work, but I'm not), and so it prints a warning: `WARNING: QApplication was not created in main() thread`.

I'd like to suppress that warning which will otherwise be printed to the X11 console and most likely cause my users to enter a bunch of needless deficiencies. However, I'd like to just supress *THIS* error, as I use `qDebug` for some legitimate purposes and want to see future warnings. Is there a way to do this, like some kind of Qt `#pragma`?

**EDIT:**

A similar question was asked before here: [Qt console application "WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077767/qt-console-application-warning-qapplication-was-not-created-in-the-main-thre?rq=1), but the answer was basically just a code review without any meaningful ideas to suppress the warning.

Comment: I think the problem arises because you're touching Qt APIs (in the main thread, or just in *some* thread) before creating QApplication. You can't do that (modulo stuff that is supposed to be done before QApplication). In particular, you're creating QObjects.

Comment: hmm, that creates an interesting chicken-egg problem, because the class I use to create the `QCoreApplication` thread is itself a `QObject` because it needs to use signals to communicate with sockets in child threads.

Comment: Well, just split it? Keep that class with the logic, and create another class that creates QCoreApplication AND an object of your class.

Comment: @peppe your two suggestions together did the trick! thanks! If you want to rephrase them as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem arises because you're touching Qt APIs (in the main thread, or just in *some* thread) before creating QApplication. You can't do that. In particular, *you're creating a QObject of some kind*, which is setting somwhere in Qt what Qt itself should consider as the `main` thread.

The only Qt APIs you're allowed to use before creating a QApplication are the ones that are explicitely documented to be safe in that scenario.

So: don't do that. **Build a QCoreApplication as the first thing**, then you're free to go.

Comment: Refactoring my code in this form also solved a lot of strange and intermittent issues I had with connections between objects in different threads. I definitely will not ignore this warning again.

Comment: @peppe is this similar when trying to plot something with matplotlib in python at PyCharm IDE? I started a bounty about it, maybe you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978377/how-to-avoid-pycharm-console-crash-when-plotting-with-matplotlib