# QFileSystemWatcher working only in main()

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemwatcher

I am trying to use QFileSystemWatcher like in the following example :
[How to use QFileSystemWatcher to monitor a folder for change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044853/how-to-qfilesystemwatcher)
My issue is that the watcher does work when I create it in the main() function like in the following :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <QFileSystemWatcher>
#include <QDebug>
#include "systemfilewatcher.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFileSystemWatcher watcher;
    watcher.addPath("C:/QtTest");
    SystemFileWatcher* mc = new SystemFileWatcher();
    QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), mc, 
                     SLOT(showModified(QString)));
    MainWindow w(&watcher);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

however when I try this exact same code in my ui like in the following, it doesn't work :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QFileSystemWatcher folder, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFileSystemWatcher watcher;
    watcher.addPath("C:/QtTest");
    SystemFileWatcher* mc = new SystemFileWatcher();
    QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), mc, SLOT(showModified(QString)));
```

this is my "systemfilewatcher.h" :

```
#ifndef SYSTEMFILEWATCHER
#define SYSTEMFILEWATCHER
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>

class SystemFileWatcher : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SystemFileWatcher(QWidget* parent=0)
        :QWidget(parent){}

    ~SystemFileWatcher(){}

public slots:
    void showModified(const QString& str)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Directory Modified", str);
    }
};
#endif // SYSTEMFILEWATCHER

     }
```

My goal is to detect when a file is created in a targeted directory and put its name in a QString stack. I don't know what I am doing wrong here, could someone help me please ?

Comment: This question amounts to a trivial mistake due to a misunderstanding of object lifetime in C++. The particular combination of that problem and Qt isn't useful to others, thus I vote to close - there's way too many incarnations of the very same problem on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, your `QFileSystemWatcher watcher` is created on the stack and is destroyed as soon as the constructor ends. You have to keep a reference to it somewhere, possibly as an attribute of your `SystemFileWatcher` class

Comment: Solved my problem by changing this line :
    QFileSystemWatcher watcher();
by this :
    QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher();

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Watch out, doing that without mantaining a reference to the object you wont be able to destroy it, you get a memory leak

Comment: @Smasho not in Qt, if the instance is a QObject-derived