# using QFileSystemWatcher::Files() to get file count of watched folder example? count is always 0?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, qfilesystemwatcher

I have tried to figure this out over the weekend, but to no avail. I cant seem to find an example using [QFileSystemWatcher::Files()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#files) directly so i thought i would ask.

I have a program that :

1. lets the user select a 'source' folder.
2. press a button to start watching that source folder for new files
3. there is a signal emitted using 'directoryChanged()' where i try to update the count every time a file is added or removed.

I will profess that my implementation of QfileSystemWatcher is probably not correct. but this code is working and does trigger the signal/slot. but the count is always zero...

from mainwindow.cpp...

the signal:

```
//connect push buttons
QObject::connect(ui->startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 this, SLOT(startButtonClicked()));

//link qfilesystemwatcher with signals and slots
    QObject::connect(&hotfolder, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(hotfolderChanged()));
```

the slots:

```
void MainWindow::startButtonClicked(){

  //start the file system watcher using the 'source folder button'
   //first, get the resulting text from the source folder button
   QString sourceText = ui->sourceBtnLineEdit->text();
   ui->statusbar->showMessage(sourceText);

   //convert the text from source button to a standard string.
   string filePath = sourceText.toStdString();
   cout << filePath << endl;

   //call method to add source path to qfilesystemwatcher
   startWatching(sourceText);

}

void MainWindow::hotfolderChanged(){

    int fileCount = filesWatched();
    ui->statusbar->showMessage(QString::number(fileCount));

}
```

from magickWatcher.h

```
#ifndef MAGICKWATCHER_H
#define MAGICKWATCHER_H

#include <QFileSystemWatcher>
#include <mainwindow.h>

//create the qFileSystemWatcher
QFileSystemWatcher hotfolder;

//add folder to qfilesystemwatcher
//starts watching of folder path
int startWatching( QString folder){

    hotfolder.addPath(folder);
    cout << "hotfolder created!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

//get file list of folder being watched
int filesWatched(){
    QStringList watchedList = hotfolder.files();

    //report out each line of file list
    for (int i = 0; i < watchedList.size(); ++i){
             cout << watchedList.at(i).toStdString() << endl;
             cout << "is this looping?!!" << endl;
    }
    return watchedList.count();
}


#endif // MAGICKWATCHER_H
```

How can i use QFileSystemWatcher to get the file count of the watched folder? I know about [QDir](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html) and its options but want to specifically know how to use QFileSystemWatcher.

I am still wrapping my head around c++ in general so thank you for any advice or tips as well. I think maybe my problem is how i am implementing QFileSystemWatcher.

Some relevant links i have used:

[QFileSystemWatcher working only in main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467830/qfilesystemwatcher-working-only-in-main)

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#files

Answer (score 1):

First let's have a closer look at docs (bold format is mine):

> `QFileSystemWatcher` examines each path added to it. **Files that have been added to the `QFileSystemWatcher` can be accessed using the `files()` function**, and directories using the `directories()` function.

So, `files()` only returns a list of files which you have already added to the watcher using `addPath()` method, NOT a list of files implicitly being watched by adding a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about files in the watched directory e.g. by using [QDir::entryInfoList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryInfoList-1) with [filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum) applicable in your case. At least `QDir::Files` and possibly `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` would make sense.

```
//get file list of folder being watched
int filesWatched() {
    QString folder = "/path/to/hotfolder/";
    QDir monitoredFolder(folder);
    QFileInfoList watchedList = 
        monitoredFolder.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files);

    QListIterator<QFileInfo> iterator(watchedList);
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        QFileInfo file_info = iterator.next();
        qDebug() << "File path:" << file_info.absoluteFilePath();
    }

    return watchedList.count();
}
```